# Why is this Open CV code leaking?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I wrote some code to add 10% grey bars to the left and right side of an image like so:

```
// Create image 20% wider
cv::Mat widenedImage(image.rows,
                     image.cols * 1.2,
                     CV_8UC1, 
                     127); // Grey colour

// Make a region of interest in the middle of the new image
cv::Mat toROI(widenedImage, cv::Rect((widenedImage.cols - image.cols) / 2.0,
                                     0,
                                     image.cols,
                                     image.rows));

// Copy the image to the region of interest 
image.copyTo(toROI);
```

Without the code, using `image` directly, the app runs fine.  When added, XCode's memory graph  does not grow, but I get several warnings followed by this message.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: And type of the image is CV_8UC1?

Comment: @Robert: Can you share the warning message as well. Additionally could you just try with the image with smaller size than the current one.

Comment: Have you tried using `static_cast<size_t>` before `cv::Rect()` and during the initialization of columns in `widenedImage`..?

Comment: @marol - Yes all the images are 8 bit with one channel.  I also double checked with `NSAssert(image.type()== CV_8UC1, @"");`.

Comment: @MantoshKumar - The message is in the screenshot.  Image is a frame from the camera, I don't really want to down-sample it.

Comment: @scap3y - I have not tried this, my C++ isn't very strong, what would that do?

Comment: So the code seems fine. The problem lays somewhere else. How do you use later widenedImage? You assing to an image variable? In your case, you have two Mat objects that actually have allocated memory for matrix data (widenedImage and image, toROI is just an header pointing to widenedImage) and only they can cause memory problems. Do you return them from the function somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I would usually create `toROI` it this way:

```
cv::Mat toROI(widenedImage(cv::Rect((widenedImage.cols - image.cols) / 2.0,
                                 0,
                                 image.cols,
                                 image.rows)));
```

or, you if you don't need `toROI` later I would suggest something like this:

```
image.copyTo(widenedImage( cv::Rect((widenedImage.cols - image.cols) / 2.0,
                                 0,
                                 image.cols,
                                 image.rows)));
```

or maybe consider using [`copyMakeBorder()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#copymakeborder).

Also, your floating-point divisions might be creating rounding errors. Try saving the size values as integers *before* using them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however both still produced the same crash :(.  The copyMakeBorder I did like this:
`int borderSize = image.cols * 0.1;`
`cv::copyMakeBorder(image, image, 0, 0, borderSize, borderSize, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);`